# How to solve these errors when generating PDF from Doxygen files?

Tags: latex, doxygen

I've generated documentation files for a C project using Doxygen. In the LaTeX folder there is a batch file that should generate a PDF file from the LaTeX files, however I get errors that I don't fully understand.

LaTeX Warning: Reference "system 8h" on page 12 undefined on input line 33.
...

Ignoring the errors ends up deleting the PDF file as soon as the batch files is done running.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is going on without knowing which version of doxygen you are using and seeing a minimal example showing the problem.

Comment: Without a MWE this is hard to diagnose.  There could be several reasons for the warning (not error) you show in your question: the first that comes to mind is to avoid spaces in label names

Comment: @albert Doxygen 1.8.15

Comment: @samcarter which labels?

Comment: @user733606 Things like `system 8h`.

Comment: @samcarter - I did not use that name

Comment: @user733606 maybe you did not use it, but the system that generated the tex file seems to have used it

Comment: @samcarter `system 8h` is probably `system_8h` and is the documentation of the file `system.h`, but like you (and I already said: without MWE it is hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: @albert Where is the crystal ball, when on needs it :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXIIz.png

Comment: @albert - MWE = minimal working example?

Comment: @samcarter indeed

Comment: @user733606 Yes MWE is Minimal Working example